# What stops me from my marking all my traffic with the highest priority?

Tags: networking, ip, qos

I am trying to understand the use of the DSCP field in an ip header. 
If I want my website to be the fastest one, why can't I just mark my packets with the highest possible priority? 
I know there is limited percentage of high priority traffic that can use the bandwidth. But my website will still be faster than others that mark their priority 0. 
When will the router use shaping to lower the priority, and what exactly is the point of using DSCP if a remote router can completely ignore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. Your QoS markings/policies will not be trusted on any other network, maybe not even in your own network because many switches will, by default, reset your markings to BE unless the port is configured to trust (non-default).

QoS needs to have a comprehensive set of policies and configurations for a network, and even if traffic is marked, unless you have queuing and shaping configured, the markings mean nothing.

You ISP will not trust or honor your markings. It may be possible to pay your ISP to do that for *some* of you markings, but as your traffic passes from it to other ISPs in the Internet, the marking will not be honored, and may be reset to BE. The destination networks would also need to honor your markings, should they survive to the destination network.